# Projection issues with QGIS 3.16 Swellendam Training data

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, buffer

I am following this QGIS 3.16 training, following it exactly as shown (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/basic_analysis.html), using their provided training data. And I am having issues with the projection. [image: In the first image, I am saving a vector layer as a GeoPackage file, under the specified CRS, WGS 84 UTM 34S. And I do this for each layer.][image: Upon saving each layer, a ? appears next to each, stating that the layer has no CRS, although I have specified the desired CRS.][image: I then click on each ? and specify the desired CRS again, this seems to cause the ? to disappear.][image: I want to perform a buffer analysis, and so I input the desired layer and specify my distance, which is 50 metres.][image: And I end up with a giant circle, which is clearly wrong.][image: I tried going to the project properties, and specify WGS 84 UTM 34S for the whole file, then repeat what I have done, and I end up with the same output. And I have no idea why?]. I tried deleting the original data, then re-downloading it, and still I am getting this issue. So I don't know if there is something wrong with the CRS, or am I doing something wrong with the Buffer analysis (although it's straight forwards so don't see where I am going wrong there)?

Any ideas?

EDIT: I have tried saving as a shapefile and working through the same process, and I still get the same issue with a ? next to the layer. And subsequently, a mal buffer analysis.
I then tried uninstalling QGIS 3.16, and downloading 3.10, and I get the same issue.

Comment: I tried it with my version of QGIS, 3.10, and I didn't get this issue, eveything seemed ok with the training data. It's strange that your exported layers have no CRS defined, they should be in UTM 34S since you specified it in the dialog.  Does it do this even if you try exporting to a shapefile or any other format?

Comment: I just tried saving as a shapefile, and again, I got a ?, then went ahead as I did previously, to change the CRS of the project, tried a buffer, and got the same output, a giant circle.